# Install/Upgrade the PDF viewer

Tags: pdf

My Document Viewer (3.4.0, using poppler/cairo 0.18.4) says "To view the full contents of this document, you need a later version of the PDF viewer. You can upgrade
to the latest version of Adobe Reader from www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html
For further support, go to www.adobe.com/support/products/acrreader.html" while opening a PDF document. I've fetched the install file (AdbeRdr9.5.1-1_i486linux_enu.bin) from the above mentioned site and put on my desktop.

How to install it?

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: How thoughtful of them to assume that there is only one PDF reader in existence...

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Which platform (32/64 bit)?

Comment: In any case the version of Adobe reader which might be installed on  Ubuntu is the .deb version.

Comment: @BlaXpirit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 32-bit